# Concatenate two data frames with string as index

Tags: python, pandas

I got two dataframes and want to combine both of them by using the country as the index.

My dataframes (head) look like the following:

human development index

```
            CPI-2016    Region
Country        
New Zealand    90    AP
Denmark        90    WE/EU
Finland        89    WE/EU
Sweden         88    WE/EU
Switzerland    86    WE/EU
```

corruption

```
             HDI-2015
Country    
Afghanistan    0.479
Albania    0.764
Algeria    0.745
Andorra    0.858
Angola    0.533
```

the concatenated one: `result = pandas.concat([hdi, cpi])`

```
            CPI-2016    HDI-2015    Region
Country         
Afghanistan NaN         0.479   NaN
Albania     NaN         0.764   NaN
Algeria     NaN         0.745   NaN
Andorra     NaN         0.858   NaN
Angola      NaN         0.533   NaN
```

and at the end there are the entries with cpi and region, but without the hdi. furthermore, there are twice as many rows as countries exist in the data.

Comment: Take a look at the pandas documentation of the join operation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: Join by index is possible with pandas

Comment: You forget `axis=1` like `result = pandas.concat([hdi, cpi], axis=1)`

Comment: Concatenating should be avoided, unless the index is always the same order. Would recommend a merge/join approach, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @jezrael same result with axis = 1. The problem is the index

Comment: what does `hdi.index.intersection(cpi.index)` say?

Comment: @JohnnyBanana - data are aligned by index - so if no row with `Afghanistan` in first dataframe get NaN.

Comment: empty array:  Index([], dtype='object',name='Country')

Comment: There you go: your dataframes have no country in common, so joining them is not giving interesting results.

Comment: they have! i can see that. but what is the problem here? doesnt it work because "countries" are object instead of strings?

Comment: They don't have any exact match. I would look at spelling mistakes. Try `cpi.index.tolist()` and `hdi.index.tolist()`, which makes it easier to see white spaces...

Comment: By the way the example you showed has no country in common.

Comment: it was just the head. now i know the matter: in the hdi table, there is a space in every entry. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `merge()`:

```
hdi.index = hdi.index.str.strip()
pd.merge(hdi, cpi, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809710/concatenate-two-data-frames-with-string-as-index#comment80567494_46809710

Comment: Thanks @jezrael completely missed that comment :)

Answer (score 0):

human_development_index.set_index('Country').join(corruption.set_index('Country'), on='Country')